# Typescript object array type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, object-type

I have this object,

```
 type Data = {
    name: 'string';
    email: 'string,';
  };

  const data:Data[] = [
    { name: 'A',email: 'a@local' },
    { name: 'B', email: 'b@local' },
  ];
```

I have type as `Data` and want to have a `const` of its type but should be array.
But, am getting error, **Type "JSON" is not assignable to type "string"**

please help.

Comment: You want `string` not `'string'` (and definitely not `'string,'`...)

Comment: oh, got it. my bad. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`const x: "string"` can only be the string `"string"`. `const y:string` can be any string. You need to remove the quotation marks from the type.